# Javascript - Controle de callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

Não sei muito bem como perguntar isso. Não tenho muito conhecimento de JS, mas vamos lá...
O sistema aqui tem uma API que adiciona e gerencia elementos na tela. Por exemplo, apenas para ilustrar: se eu colocar `API.adicionar(tipo.CampoTexto, "idNome", posicao)`, ele adiciona um `input` com determinada ID em determinada posição.

Dito isso, tenho essa estrutura de JSON:

```
{
    "parent 1": [
        {
            "key 1.1.1": "item 1.1.1",
            "key 1.1.2": "item 1.1.2",
            "key 1.1.3": "item 1.1.3"
        },
        {
            "key 1.2.1": "item 1.2.1",
            "key 1.2.2": "item 1.2.2",
            "key 1.2.3": "item 1.2.3"
        },
      ],
      "parent 2": [
        {
            "key 2.1.1": "item 2.1.1",
            "key 2.1.2": "item 2.1.2",
            "key 2.1.3": "item 2.1.3"
        },
        {
            "key 2.2.1": "item 2.2.1",
            "key 2.2.2": "item 2.2.2",
            "key 2.2.3": "item 2.2.3"
        }
    ]
}
```

O problema é que eu preciso agrupar esse dados da forma como está no JSON: aninhado. Quando uso a API para adicionar o `parent 1`, preciso especificar quantos itens irão com ele. No caso do exemplo acima, seriam 6 campos (preciso dividir 3 para cada objeto).

Tenho uma variável que guarda a quantidade de campos que foram adicionados e basicamente ela está se perdendo, pois quando eu adiciono um campo, até o tempo de renderização, ele já passou por outra instrução/condição e iniciou a configuração de outro campo para renderizar...

Como posso fazer essas correntes para iniciar a parte apenas quando outra já estiver concluída?

Segue um pouco de código (tenho liberdade pra jogar tudo no lixo e começar de novo, ok?)

```
var _objetoDados;

function DadosAgrupados(index, numeroCamposAdicionados) {
    this.index = index;

    // json vem de um HTTP Request no formato acima
    this.agrupamento = Object.values(json)[this.index];
    this.tituloAuditado = Object.keys(json)[this.index];
    this.numeroCamposAdicionados = numeroCamposAdicionados;
}

DadosAgrupados.prototype.agrupa = function(callback) {
    callback.call(this);
}

DadosAgrupados.prototype.retornaIndice = function() {
    return this.index;
}

DadosAgrupados.prototype.somaNumeroCamposAdicionados = function() {
    this.numeroCamposAdicionados++;
}

DadosAgrupados.prototype.retornaNumeroCamposAdicionados = function() {
    return this.numeroCamposAdicionados;
}

function montaDados() {

    var objetoAgrupado = this.agrupamento;
    var tamanhoItens = Object.keys(consolidado).length;

    if (!API.campo("CAMPO_TESTE").existe()) {

        /* PRIMEIRA ADIÇÃO - FUNCIONA OK */

        _objetoDados.somaNumeroCamposAdicionados();

        //Esse método não é necessário para a lógica do problema
        configuraDadosHTML(1, objetoAgrupado[0]);

        API.campo("CAMPO_TESTE").adicionaCamposAninhados(tamanhoItens - 1);
        API.campo("CAMPO_TESTE").adicionaEvento('tipoEspecificoCallback', function (e) {
            var indice = e.data.campo.indice - 1;

            _objetoDados.somaNumeroCamposAdicionados();

            //Até aqui, indice é o número de campos que foram adicionados
            configuraDadosHTML(indice, objetoAgrupado[indice - 1]);

            if (indice > (tamanhoItens - 1)) {
                criaNovoAgrupamento();
            }

        });
    }
    else {

        /** AQUI COMEÇA O PROBLEMA, O QUARTO ITEM ADICIONA NORMALMENTE, DEPOIS JÁ PERDE OS VALORES DE INDICE DE CAMPOS ADICIONADOS */
        else {
        _objetoDados.somaNumeroCamposAdicionados();
        configuraDadosTituloRepeticaoConsolidado(_objetoDados.retornaNumeroCamposAdicionados(), objetoAgrupado[0]);

        if (tamanhoItens > 1) {
            API.campo("CAMPO_TESTE").adicionaCamposAninhados(tamanhoItens - 1);
            API.campo("CAMPO_TESTE").adicionaEvento('tipoEspecificoCallback', function (e) {
                var indice = e.data.campo.indice - 1;

                _objetoDados.somaNumeroCamposAdicionados();
                configuraDadosHTML(_objetoDados.retornaNumeroCamposAdicionados(), objetoAgrupado[tamanhoItens - indice]);
                criaNovoAgrupamento();
            });
        }
        else {
            criaNovoAgrupamento();
        }
    }
    }
}

function criaNovoAgrupamento() {
    var novoIndice = 0;
    var camposAdicionados = 0;

    if (_objetoDados != undefined) {
        novoIndice = _objetoDados.retornaIndice() + 1;

        if (Object.keys(json)[novoIndice] == undefined) {
            return;
        }
        camposAdicionados = _objetoDados.retornaNumeroCamposAdicionados();
    }

    _objetoDados = new DadosAgrupados(novoIndice, camposAdicionados);
    _objetoDados.agrupa(montaDados);
}
```

Comment: Como vc precisa que uma chamada termina para que outra comece, seria interessanrte vc usar promise nessas suas chamadas à API: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-br